# CoreOS VM crash: swap trace printed

Tags: linux-kernel, swap, kubernetes, coreos, page-fault

I'm using CoreOS 773.1.0 with kubernetes. Recently it crashes and printed this trace log:

[image]

[image]

The VM is still running but I cannot ssh to it, kubernetes master node declare it as `NotReady`. I had to turn it off (not shutdown) and start it.

I'm using Hyper-V as hypervisor, the VM is assiged 12GB RAM, 4GB swap, 4 cores CPU. Especially, I got this error after I moved the disk (`.vhd` file) to new partition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue to CoreOS 717.3.0 with swap: https://github.com/coreos/bugs/issues/429

Comment: Thanks, I have noticed that

Answer (score 1):

Based on the stack trace, it looks like the kernel was trying to free up memory.  So, probably the node was under severe memory pressure.  Kernel bugs tend to crop up under memory pressure.

It also looks like swap was turned on. Kubernetes developers don't recommend turning on swap.

Comment: Can you explain why they don't recommend turning on swap, specifically in CoreOS, or generally?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Kubelet process is stucked. Do you have kubelet log and at which operation, kubelet is stucked?

Comment: No, I couldn't access kubelet logs because the entire host was hang. I had to turn it of. When turned on, the journal logs was erased